# Weighted Kappa – how to calculate the 95%CI correct – and is it allowed to include 1.00?

Tags: r, sas, cohens-kappa

I have got into the problem, that I have three codes providing me with two different results for the 95%-CI…

Results, weighted kappa estimate (95%-CI):

Code 1: 0.77 (0.45 to 1.1)

Code 2: 0.7665 (0.4459 to 1.0000)

Code 3: 0.77 (0.55951 to 0.88718)

- Code 1: R (based on psych package)
- Code 2: SAS, based on PROC FREQ
  following this guide:
  http://www.agreestat.com/research_papers/inter_rater_reliability_with_sas.pdf
  (and more info here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_freq_a0000000665.htm
  )
- Code 3: SAS, following a code I don’t know where originally
  originates from, neigther does the one that suggests I am using it.
  Nb this does only calculate the 95%-CI.

The argument for me to use code 3 is that the 95%-CI for weighted Kappa should NOT have a upper limit (UL) above 1, since the estimate for weighted Kappa kan only be between -1 and +1. However in the pdf example for code 2, they DO show results with a 95%-CI-UL above 1 on page 7 (however, when I do the example myself, it goes to 1.00, indicating that SAS has changed codes since 2002).

- So which of the codes results in correct calculation?
- Also, do any of you recognize code 3?
- And should I round the 95%CI-UL down to be 1.00 instead of 1.1?

### Codes:

Code 1:

```
library(psych)

R1<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
R2<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
M<-as.matrix(R1,nrow=26,ncol=1);M<-cbind(M,R2);M<-as.data.frame(M)

cohen.kappa(M[,1:2])
```

Code 2:

```
DATA ClassData;
INPUT Subject$ R1 R2;
DATALINES;
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 1 0
6 0 0
7 0 0
8 1 1
9 1 1
10 0 0
11 0 0
12 2 2
13 0 0
14 0 0
15 1 0
16 1 0
17 0 0
18 0 0
19 0 0
20 0 0
21 0 0
22 0 0
23 0 0
24 0 0
25 0 0
26 0 0
;
RUN;

PROC FREQ DATA = ClassData;
TABLES R1*R2/AGREE(WT=FC);
TEST KAPPA;
RUN;
```

Code 3:

```
Data DATA;
Input Name$ N R;
vR1=((1-R)**2)/2;
vR2=(((1+R)**2)/n +((1-R)*(1+3*R)+4*(R**2))/(n-1));
VR=VR1*VR2;
L=(0.5*log((1+R)/(1-R)))-(1.96*sqrt(VR))/((1+R)*(1-R));
U=(0.5*log((1+R)/(1-R)))+(1.96*sqrt(VR))/((1+R)*(1-R));
R_Low=(exp(2*L)-1)/(exp(2*L)+1);
R_Up=(exp(2*U)-1)/(exp(2*U)+1);
datalines;
Faktor2 26 0.77
;
Proc Print;
Var N  R R_Low R_Up ;
Run;
```